# How can I theme Google Map in Flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, themes

I have a map app that I want to change theme at sunrise and sunset. Theming the map should be very simple, but I am getting the following error.

> Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'setMapStyle' was called on null.

Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
  - assets/themes/map/day/
  - assets/themes/map/night/
```

I have imported the following package.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
```

I have added the following line to my initState()

```
rootBundle.loadString('assets/themes/map/night/night.json').then((string) {
      _mapStyle = string;
    });
```

Here is my map controller.

```
Completer<GoogleMapController> _mapController = Completer();

void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup
            .locationWhenInUse) //check permission returns a Future
        .then(_updateStatus); // handling in callback to prevent blocking UI

    _mapController.complete(
     controller); // manages camera function (position, animation, zoom).

    controller.setMapStyle(_mapStyle);
    print("MAPSTYLE -> $_mapStyle");
  }
```

and here is the start of my map code

```
_userLocation == null
    ? Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            backgroundColor: Theme.UniColour.primary[900],
        ))
        : GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            initialCameraPosition:
                CameraPosition(
                    target: _userLocation,
                    zoom: _defaultZoom,
                    tilt: _tiltAngle),
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
```

Any helped would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me.

```
controller.setMapStyle(await rootBundle.loadString('assets/styles/google_map.json'));
```

Using async await to prevent race condition.

Comment: So are you saying changing void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) { to void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async { then change my rootbundle line to what you have?

Comment: I have added detailed usage of google map here: https://arkapp.medium.com/flutter-and-google-map-for-beginners-part-1-fdba4ab22148